# Intersection of four planes

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have some difficulties with a problem, where i have been given four planes:
$$x+ay+az=a$$
$$x+a^2y=a^3$$
$$x+a^2y+az=a$$
$$x+ay+2az=a,$$
and need to find the points in $M$, where any point belongs to $M$, if it contains the coordinates $4$ and $-4$, and there is an $a$ in which it lies in all four planes.

I know how to reduce the system of equations to reduced row echelon form,  and have also found values of $a$, where they all intersect, but i can't seem to find a way to solve this specific problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am still a little bit confused. What exactly is $M$, and what do you mean by: "it contains the coordinates $4$ and $-4$,"? I assume the planes lie in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: $M$ is a set of points, where all the points in $M$ need to have $4$ and $-4$ as two of their coordinates. There also needs to exist an $a$ in which a point in $M$ lies in all four planes. And yes, the planes lie in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I believe you are looking for any points satisfying the following conditions:

(i) There must be at least one $\:4\:$ **and** one $\:-4\:$ among the coordinates; and

(ii) There must be at least one $\:a\:$ such that the point lies on all four planes.

We start by simplifying the conditions.

a) If $\:a=0\:$, then all equations become $\:x=0\:$, which yields the four points $\:(0,\pm 4, \pm 4)\:$.

b) If $\:a \neq 0\:$, then combining the first and last equations gives $\:z=0\:$, and combining the second and third equations gives $\:a=\pm 1\:$. If $\:a=1\:$, all four equations become $\:x+y=1\:$; if $\:a=-1\:$, we get the system $\:x-y=-1\:$ and $\:x+y=-1\:$. However, neither case allows for a solution containing a $\:4\:$ **and** a $\:-4\:$.

So under the stated conditions, the only solutions would be the four points $\:(0,\pm 4, \pm 4)\:$.

**However**, if the conditions were loosened slightly so that the first condition became

(i) There must be at least one $\:4\:$ **or** one $\:-4\:$ among the coordinates

then case a) would yield all the points on the four lines $\:x=0, y=\pm 4\:$ and $\:x=0, z=\pm 4\:$;

and case b) with $\:a=1\:$ would yield the points: $\:(5,-4,0),(4,-3,0),(-3,4,0)\:$ and $\:(-4,5,0)\:$.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not understand the question in detail, it is clear by direct computation that the system has exactly the following solutions over a field of characteristic zero. Either we have
$$
z=0,\; a=1,\; x+y=1,
$$
or we have
$$
a=x=0,
$$
or we have 
$$
z=0,\; x=-1,\; y=0.
$$
In particular, the last solution holds for arbitrary $a\in K$.